# Looking for mathematically "rigorous" problem sets to practice Microeconomics at the intermediate level

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request

I am looking for decent resources to practice and learn Microeconomics. I need problems that are more involved unlike the ones in Varian's Workbook. For this, I decided to use Nicholson and Snyder (NS) and Lecture Notes by Ariel Rubinstein.  The major issue with Rubinstein is that there's no solution manual. I found a similar course offered by Dirk Bergemann in 2012, and he in fact used the book by NS. Here's the course: https://campuspress.yale.edu/dirkbergemann/teaching/econ-121b-2012/.

If you know of a site, course or a (free e-) book that provides problems of at least a similar level, please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for intermediate level problem sets with detailed (and mathematically rigorous?) solutions, not "rigorous resources" in general, so the title is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Also, based on [your previous questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/33107/dictatemetokcus?tab=questions) I would say your micro course is more likely to be at the advanced level than at the intermediate level.

Comment: @Giskard The course (excluding the game theory part) is designed in the vein of Varian and NS, and not at the graduate level. It's Intermediate Micro (from the theoretical perspective), although the problems will be more involved. I am fine with Grad level courses, but the theoretical knowledge required is usually more than what I need (or will be able to finish). This is precisely why I am looking only for Problems.